# I can't mute audio on Chrome with auto policy

Tags: html, google-chrome, autoplay

I have Chrome beta M70 and audio is not disabled. I switch flag #autoplay-policy to **Document user activation is required**. 
After this I open my site with `HTML5` game and audio play normal. How to disable audio to test before version 70 stable comes out?

Chrome blog: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 0):

Sometime between Monday evening and Wednesday of this week, they updated that post (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio) to say that the autoplay policy will launch in M71 for the Web Audio API. There hasn't been any wider announcement about pushing back that change, which is pretty disappointing, but it *is* now reflected in the Chrome 71 changelogs as well.